# Remove a specified character while i using print in python

Tags: python

Hi: I am new to python and programing.
I have a silly question that I couldn't solve.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in a:
    print(i,end=' ')
```

will get a out put:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

There are space between each numbers in the system out print: ( `s` means space)

```
1s2s3s4s5s
```

How can I remove the last space? The correct out put will be :

```
1s2s3s4s5
```

Comment: `print(i,end=' ', sep='')`

Comment: You might find `join` useful.

Comment: this is a common "Programmingtask" for sites like Codechef, Hackerrank etc. and plenty of solutions online...

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(' '.join([str(x) for x in a])
```

This will first convert each element of 'a' to string and then join all element using join(). It must be noted that ' ' can be replaced with any other symbol as well

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways, but a simple way is `join`:

```
print(' '.join(a), end='')
```

You can also directly use `print`:

```
print(*a, sep=' ', end='')
```

Comment: `print(' '.join(a), end='')` will throw an error without an explicit cast